# Mapping Msg using NoMap in Elm with http request on init

Tags: types, functional-programming, elm, elm-architecture

I am building my first Elm application, and i'm structuring it according to theese sources:

[How i structure elm apps](http://blog.jenkster.com/2016/04/how-i-structure-elm-apps.html)

[NoMap approach with Domain focus](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/structured-elm-todomvc)

Which means i map my `Msg` types from my main `Types.elm` to my child functions. Which looks like this when doing a simple `onClick` function

`onClick (MsgForPieChart <| SelectSlice <| sliceModel.points)`

Now i want to fetch some data on init for a view.

I tried following the same approach as for a simple `onClick` function

```
getWarAndPeace : Cmd Msg
getWarAndPeace =
    Http.send (MsgForMuseums <| FetchedMuseums) <|
        Http.getString "https://example.com/books/war-and-peace.md"
```

Where my main type look like this:

```
type Msg
= MsgForPieChart Atom.PieChart.Types.Msg
| MsgForMuseums Organism.Museums.Types.Msg 
| NoOp
```

And my child function type looks like this for `http` requests

```
type Msg = 
FetchedMuseums (Result Http.Error String)
```

But no matter what i try i keep getting type errors like this from `Http.send` or `Task`or whatever approach i try

```
Result Http.Error a -> App.Types.Msg
```

But it is:

```
App.Types.Msg
```

My update functions is structured like:

```
update : App.Types.Msg -> Organism.Museums.Types.MuseumsModel -> Organism.Museums.Types.MuseumsModel
update msgFor model =
case msgFor of
    MsgForMuseums msg ->
        updateMuseums msg model
    _ ->
        model


updateMuseums : Organism.Museums.Types.Msg -> Organism.Museums.Types.MuseumsModel -> Organism.Museums.Types.MuseumsModel
updateMuseums msg model =
    case msg of
        FetchedMuseums data -> model
```

So how do i fetch `http` requests on init for my child function, which is using the NoMap pattern to combine `Msg`

Comment: Try `Http.send (MsgForMuseums << FetchedMuseums)`?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, which let me to another problem i can't call a `Cmd Msg` from a sub function init? Which is then put together in my main init

Answer (score 1):

Using `Http.send (MsgForMuseums << FetchedMuseums)` as suggested by Dogbert did solve the issue